# Extension Function to convert string to ascii

Tags: kotlin

I want to create and extension function of String which takes a String and returns a new String that contains ascii codes of each character of passed string. How can I do this? I am new to Kotlin.

Comment: Note: a String is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. (UTF-16 is one of several character encodings for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set.) All of the answers so far convert to the UTF-16 code units to a numeric type. This has nothing to do with the ASCII character set.

Comment: Try it on some real-world characters like [☺](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm) and [](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F6B2/index.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same solution as @mTak, but relying on more standard library functions, namely [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) and [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html):

```
fun String.toAscii() = this.map { it.toInt() }.joinToString()
```

Comment: Relevant to know that `it` in the first `map` is of type `Char` (`fun <R> CharSequence.map(transform: (Char) -> R): List<R>`)

Comment: @zsmb13 Can you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Separated by commas:

```
fun String.toAscii(): String {
    var s = ""
    for (char in this) {
        s = s + char.toInt() + ","
    }

    return s.removeSuffix(",")
}
```

if you prefer lambdas:

```
fun String.toAscii(): String {
    var s = ""
    this.forEach { s = s + it.toInt() + "," }
    return s.removeSuffix(",")
}
```

use it like: `println("abc".toAscii())`

Answer (score 0):

String extension function which takes a String and returns a new String that contains ASCII codes of each character of the passed string.

```
fun String.stringToAscii(): String {
    var asciiStr = ""
    val iterator = iterator()
    for (i in iterator) {
        asciiStr += (i.toInt().toString() + ",")
    }
    return asciiStr.removeSuffix(",")
}
```

Then you can use this extension function by the below code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("41hjhfaf".stringToAscii())
}
```

Output: `52,49,104,106,104,102,97,102`